# ExtJS/CSS--button background color not showing in IE8

Tags: css, extjs

I added some minor css styling to my button and it works fine in FireFox and Chrome and IE11 but not IE8

CSS

```
.search-button  {
    background:#00A300 !important;
    border-radius:20px !important;
    background-image: none !important;

}

.search-button .x-btn-inner {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

BUTTON

```
          xtype: "button",
          itemId:"searchBtn",
          text: "<b>Search &gt;&gt;</b>",
          formBind: true,
          cls:"search-button"
        //baseCls:null
```

thanks

Edit: one thing I just noticed when I hover over the button or click it, its shows my background color around the border which then disappears on mouseout or depress of the button

I am using Ext 4.2.2

Comment: If you use one of the original sencha themes, you should make a screenshot and submit it to official Sencha forum, for it could be a bug. Have you tried to set the background color on `x-btn-inner` instead?

Comment: hey, .search-button .x-btn-inner works in IE8 but of course this only covers the background of the "inner" btn and not the whole button.

Comment: my app is using the Gray theme. It just might be a bug, I'm going to try and contact Sencha directly. I've actually already posed this same question in Sencha forum but no luck yet

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in our App using ExtJS 4.2.2 with Gray Theme in IE8. EDIT: Please try whether it works when you remove baseCls:null.

Comment: hi, adding/removing baseCls:null has no effect, at least not in IE. Ive commented it out